# SVN+SSH authentication isses when running CruiseControl.NET 1.4.4 SP1 service on Windows Server 2003

Tags: svn, ssh, cruisecontrol.net, windows-server-2003

The SVN+SSH protocol works great for the logged-in user because we have Pageant (PuTTY authentication agent) running in the background for that user. When we try to run the ccservice (as opposed to the ccnet.exe app) the svn+ssh fails. What am I missing in the config to get it working?

```
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
  <project name="ProjectXCore" queue="ProjectXQueue" queuePriority="1">

    <workingDirectory>D:\cc\ProjectX\code\trunk\src\</workingDirectory>
    <artifactDirectory>D:\cc\ProjectX\artifact\</artifactDirectory>

    <category>ProjectX</category>
    <webURL>http://localhost/ccnet/</webURL>
    <modificationDelaySeconds>30</modificationDelaySeconds>
    <labeller type="defaultlabeller">
      <prefix>0.1.</prefix>
      <incrementOnFailure>true</incrementOnFailure>
      <labelFormat>000</labelFormat>
    </labeller>
    <state type="state" directory="State" />

    <sourcecontrol type="svn">
      <trunkUrl>svn+ssh://10.10.2.19/srv/svn/ProjectX/trunk/src</trunkUrl>
      <workingDirectory>D:\cc\ProjectX\code\trunk\src</workingDirectory>
      <executable>C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn.exe</executable>
      <username>super</username>
      <password>duper</password>
      <timeout units="minutes">5</timeout>
    </sourcecontrol>
```

TortoiseSvn is installed on the server if that helps. I'm not sure if I need to add some command-line switches to get it to work or what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out, this config is working:

```
 <sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <trunkUrl>svn+ssh://10.10.10.10/srv/svn/ProjectX/trunk/src</trunkUrl>
  <workingDirectory>D:\cc\ProjectX\code\trunk\src</workingDirectory>
  <executable>C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe</executable>
  <buildArgs> -N -L 3690:localhost:3690 -l super -pw duper -i "C:\Documents and Settings\Super\id_rsa.ppk" -ssh 10.10.10.10 | "C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn.exe" </buildArgs>
  <username>super</username>
  <password>duper</password>
  <timeout units="minutes">5</timeout>
</sourcecontrol>
```

I take it back, that config didn't work, an older version of the config was cached :-(

This one is working now though:

```
<sourcecontrol type="svn">
  <trunkUrl>svn+ssh://10.10.2.19/srv/svn/ProjectX/trunk/src</trunkUrl>
  <workingDirectory>D:\cc\ProjectX\code\trunk\src</workingDirectory>
  <executable>"C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin\svn.exe"</executable>
  <username>super</username>
  <password>duper</password>
  <timeout units="minutes">5</timeout>
</sourcecontrol>
```